Proof of completeness of $\mathbb{R}$
I was struggling with the proof I found in a book (Analisi Matematica 1, Pagani-Salsa), about completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ that is quite different from every other proof of it I've ever seen. The theorem states that given $A \subset \mathbb{R}, A \neq \emptyset, \forall x \in A \exists M \in \mathbb{R}:M\geq x$, which means $A$ has an upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$.
The proof construct some intervals like this, let $A$ be infinite, then take $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}:y_0 \geq x $ where $x$ is any element of $A$, then take $x_0 \in A$ and create the interval $[x_0,y_0]$, then you can divide in half the interval by choosing $c = \frac{x_0+y_0}{2}$ and creating the intervals $[x_0,c], [c,y_0]$, now choose one of the two like this: choose the one with elements of $A$ in it or, if both have elements of $A$ choose the second, and write the new interval like this $[x_1,y_1]$. Now suppose that the process is iterated $n$ times, then the set $[x_n,y_n]$ has this properties,

$[x_0,y_0] \supset [x_1,y_1] \supset \dots \supset [x_n,y_n]$

$y_n - x_n = \frac{y_0-x_0}{2^n}$ and $[x_n,y_n]$ contains elements of $A$

$\forall x \in A \quad \text{and}\quad \forall n\quad y_n \geq x $

$\{x_n\}$ is a non decreasing sequence that is limited above by $y_0$ then it converges to $\overline{x}$


Then they want to demonstrate that $\overline{x} = \sup(A)$ one of the properties of the $\sup(A)$, $\forall\epsilon > 0 \quad \exists x \in A:x > \sup(A) -\epsilon$. They suppose that $\overline{x}$ is not the least upper bound, then there exists $\epsilon : \forall n\ \quad \overline{x}-\epsilon < \overline{x} \leq y_n,\quad \forall x \in A\quad \overline{x}-\epsilon \geq x$, so the interval $[\overline{x} - \epsilon, y_n]$ doesn't contain elements of $A$. And now comes the part that I don't understand: $\overline{n}$ is chosen such that $y_{\overline{n}} - x_{\overline{n}} = \frac{y_0-x_0}{2^{\overline{n}}} < \epsilon$ then $[x_\overline{n},y_\overline{n}] \subset [\overline{x} - \epsilon, y_\overline{n}]$ and this is a contradiction since $[x_\overline{n},y_\overline{n}]$ must contain elements of $A$ by point 2. The part that I don't understand is why taking $\overline{n}$ such that $y_{\overline{n}} - x_{\overline{n}} = \frac{y_0-x_0}{2^{\overline{n}}} < \epsilon$ entails $[x_\overline{n},y_\overline{n}] \subset [\overline{x} - \epsilon, y_\overline{n}]$.

If you want to say $A$ is bounded from above, you should switch the order of the quantifiers.

I think what's missing here is the fact that $\overline{x} \in [x_n, y_n]$ for all $n$. Note that, because $x_n$ is non-decreasing and limits to $\overline{x}$, we have $x \le \overline{x}$. On the other hand, if we had $y_n < \overline{x}$, then we would have $x_m \le y_m \le y_n < \overline{x}$ for all $m \ge n$, which means the sequence $x_n$ will eventually lie at least $\varepsilon = \overline{x} - y_n > 0$ distance away from its ostensible limit of $\overline{x}$, which contradicts the definition of a limit. As such, $\overline{x} \le y_n$, so $\overline{x} \in [x_n, y_n]$ as claimed.
Now, we have $y_{\overline{n}} - x_{\overline{n}} < \varepsilon$, and from above, $x_{\overline{n}} \le \overline{x} \le y_{\overline{n}}$. Then,
$$\overline{x} \le y_{\overline{n}} < x_{\overline{n}} + \varepsilon \implies \overline{x} - \varepsilon < x_{\overline{n}}.$$
Hence
$$[x_{\overline{n}}, y_{\overline{n}}] \subseteq [\overline{x} - \varepsilon, y_{\overline{n}}],$$
as required.
